# Determine if a positive integer is a sum of two positive squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Given a positive integer $N$, what is the best/most efficient way to determine if $N=x^2+y^2$ for some *positive* integers $x<y$? Only the decision is needed, not explicitly $x,y$.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163563), $n$ is the sum of two non-negative squares if and only if for each prime $p\equiv3\pmod4$, $p$ appears with even exponent in the factorization of $n$.

If the factorization of $n$ contains at least one prime $p\equiv1\pmod4$ with positive exponent, or $p=2$ with odd exponent, then $n$ can be written as the sum of two positive squares.

If the factorization of $n$ contains at least one prime $p\equiv1\pmod4$ with positive exponent, then $n$ can be written as the sum of two distinct positive squares.

Comment: Does that ensure $x<y$? That is, $x$ and $y$ are distinct?

Comment: @JoeYang: I have appended my answer to give the condition for distinct positive squares.

Answer (score 1):

[Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) (not [that one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)) states that a prime $p$ is a sum of two squares if and only if $p=2$ or $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. This extends to the rest of the integers using the relation
$$ (x^2+y^2)(z^2+w^2) = (xz-yw)^2+(xw+yz)^2. $$
Therefore any product of primes of the form $4k+1$ is also expressible as the sum of two squares. If $N$ contains prime factors of the form $4k+3$, they must occur to even powers (it is clear that even powers just merge into both squares). The hard part is proving that any integer with an odd power of a $4k+3$ is not thus expressible, but you'll find the proof in any number theory book.

So: find the prime factorisation of $N$, and look at the prime factors that are $3 \pmod{4}$. $N$ is a sum of two squares if and only if all such prime factors occur to even powers.

Answer (score -1):

Fermat's Theorem says,

> If $p$ is an odd prime and $x,y$ are integers numbers. $p=x^2+y^2$ iff $p≡1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Isn't $p$ an odd prime?

Comment: @Shahab Yes, sorry.

Comment: That only begins to answer the general question.